# Why is GDB not able to see my local variable?

Tags: c++, gdb, fork, remote-debugging, child-process

### Why is GDB not able to see my local variable i ?

I am debugging a multi-process application running on an embedded linux device.
I am having a hard time attaching to a child process (note that I cannot start the child process by itself, it needs the parent to run it. )

Using `set follow-fork-mode child` did not work (gdb hangs while loading dynamic libraries).

My strategy is to have this in my code to stop the child

```
#ifdef DEBUG

int i = 0;

while (i == 0)
{
    usleep(100000);  // sleep for 0.1 seconds
}

#endif // DEBUG
```

To have time to attach to the child using `gdbserver --attach :1234 <child-pid>` and then, after setting a break point where I want (line 200 in main.cpp), to issue the following command in gdb : `set var i = 1` to break out of the while loop.

This isn't working and I am wondering why. Here is the output from gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ff3feab7ff0 in nanosleep () from target:/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ff3feae1c14 in usleep () from target:/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x000055cc4e56908a in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>)
    at platform/aas/intc/ucmclient/src/main.cpp:195
(gdb) break main.cpp:200
Breakpoint 1 at 0x55cc4e56908c: file platform/aas/intc/ucmclient/src/main.cpp, line 200.
(gdb) set var i=1
No symbol "i" in current context.
```

The backtrace seems to show I am in the while loop. Why then is the variable i not in the locals?

Comment: Your program is currently inside `nanosleep()` function from the standard library according to backtrace. Likely there is no `i` at this scope.

Comment: And even if it's not in nanosleep, the compiler might've optimized it out entirely.

Comment: I see, so there must be a better way to achieve my goal of attaching to the child process ?